# Can server-side caching misconfiguration lead to stolen logins?

Tags: http, http-proxy, caching

If a webapp sends `Cache-Control: private` it shouldn't be cached for example with nginx `proxy_cache`. What could happen if it was cached anyhow? Could another visitor see the personalized login of another user? Might another visitor then being logged in as another user?

Comment: That will depend on how it was cached and what access to the cache other clients would have.